# RStudio data viewer showing Greek characters instead of English

Tags: r, view, localization, rstudio

I am a newbie, loading data (`data(iris)`) into R. Everything is fine but when I do `View(iris)`, the Species names in the table are shown in a different language. Wondering if there's a bug or something? Please see an example below.

[image: iris]

**Some details that might be helpful in understanding the issue:**
R version 4.0.1 (2020-06-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

locale:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y20sc.png) LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252

Answer (score 0):

Try to run [`Sys.getlocale()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/locales.html) in RStudio, maybe you have some config problem in localization:

```
Sys.getlocale()
```

If you see something unexpected (like some different language settings etc.), you can set this to all to English:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","English")
#> [1] "LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United States.1252"
```

See more in [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/locales.html) - hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. Although the system language is already English, I still tried your suggestion but it didn't work.

> `Sys.getlocale()`
[1] "LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252"`

Comment: @Shurli Wow, that's strange! Is your R's welcome message and RStudio interface in English except this viewer? Now I see that the line under the table is properly in English ("showing 1 to 9 entries, 5 total columns") but displayed in Greek letters... really weird.

Comment: Yes, everything else is in English but the text in this viewer. I know, it's weird. Even if I Copy and Paste these Greek letters, they are pasted in normal English :(. I have been struggling with this but neither do I get anywhere nor did I get a response from the experts.

Comment: @Shurli This is soooo weird. Maybe try to right-click directly on the line "Showing 1 to 9 entries, 5 total columns", then choose "Inspect element". Don't know if you are familiar with HTML, but it should open RStudio DevTools with HTML source of that line. And maybe you'll see if it's in greek in the source code or if it's another problem: in my case it shows `<div class="dataTables_info" id="rsGridData_info" role="status" aria-live="polite">Showing 1 to 9 of 150 entries, 5 total columns</div>`

Comment: you won't believe I have tried that too. In the source code, it shows up in English - just like yours. Please see below:
`<div class="dataTables_info" id="rsGridData_info" role="status" aria-live="polite">Showing 1 to 20 of 150 entries, 5 total columns</div>`

Comment: @Shurli Oh, thanks, it's great you have tried! And if you do that and open "Computed" style tab on the right side of the DevTools, what font-family does it say? In my case it's displayed in ["Dejavu Sans"](https://i.imgur.com/CTHcix8.png) etc. In the meantime I found a piece of code that should show here, it's from the DataTables javascript plugin, however, the translation to Greek should be as follows on [GitHub](https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins/blob/master/i18n/Greek.lang#L12-L13), not English written in Greek... Still trying to find out what's going on :-)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me out here. In my "Computed" style, the font-family is the same as yours:
`DejaVu Sans', 'Lucida Grande', 'Segoe UI', Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif`

Comment: I have something interesting to share. May be, you can look at it with your expert eye to nail the issue. Here's what I found. I right clicked on the line _Showing 1 to 20 of 150 entries, 5 total columns_ and inspected in Styles (in DevTools) the last piece of code (body{}) which has _font-family_ in it. The list in _font-family_ is _'DejaVu Sans', 'Lucida Grande', 'Segoe UI', Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif_. When I remove/delete ___'DejaVu Sans'___ from the list, the font in the table appears in English. It seems as if there's something wrong with the 'DejaVu Sans' font(?).

Comment: @Shurli Thanks for your info! I'm playing with that every day, it's like a detective story, a game of life and death for me. :-) The point is that it's really not easy to display letters in Greek on the web instead of the Latin ones in the source code (and RStudio is kind of web app in this case), it requires some intention and extra code - and I still can't find those. "DejaVu Sans" should be OK in your case, because the table header (Sepal.Length etc.) is in that font as well... But if you change font and the table appears in English, it's at least a useful trace. I'll check that, thanks :-)

Comment: @Shurli Just want you to know than I didn't forget. :-) But I can't find the solution and even reproduce the error. I realized that you created the [issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/7358) for this at GitHub, so I wonder if anybody will be able to find solution to this really weird situation...

Comment: Thanks for still trying to help me out. I have posted my issue in a couple of other places but no luck so far.

Comment: If this if of any use, that's not Greek, it's English *written with Greek characters* (transliterated). For example, "columns" in Greek would be "στήλες", whilst in your example it's "χολυμνσ" - letter by letter, c-o-l-u-m-n-s. I notice the issue was closed on GH.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue recently. On a computer that didn't have this issue, I noticed that it did not have any DejaVu fonts installed. Then on the computer with the issue, I saw that it had "DejaVu Symbol" installed, but no others from the DejaVu family.

I installed all the DejaVu TTF fonts on the computer from (https://dejavu-fonts.github.io/Download.html) and the issue was resolved. Removing DejaVu Symbol would have also fixed it, but I didn't know if that would negatively affect other software.

Comment: Thanks @Russell. I’ll keep your tip in mind the next time I face this issue. Cheers